# Find a date in the past, always based off of todays date

Tags: sql, groovy

Here is our current string:

```
select * 
from trailer 
where trailer.company_id = 'TMS' 
  and (trailer.is_active = 'A' or trailer.is_active = 'S') 
  and (trailer.inspection_date >= {d '2019-03-26'})
```

Problem is the date - I need this to always be 335 days in the past based on todays date - so always >=(todays date -335)

Groovy Console version 2.0.1 - running it on a McLeod LoadMaster version 17.2.0

Comment: Tag your question properly!!!  Functions, especially date functions vary widely for different dbms.

Comment: Please read this for a guide how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That's a niche date literal format, there. I used to have to use that running up against an old mainframe. @Eric is right. Until we know what database product (or products...) you're working with, no one will be able to give you any useful advice.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You sill need the tag, but: MySQL: `select adddate(current_date(),-335);`    PostgreSQL: `select (now() - INTERVAL '335 day');`   MS-SQL: `SELECT DATEADD(day,-335,GETDATE());`

Comment: Oops,, i forgot SQLite: `select date('now','-335 day');`

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: Maybe you use Access, than the answer would be: `select DATEADD("d",-335,DATE())`...... 

Comment: @Luuk Oracle: `SYSDATE - 335`

Comment: @Luuk why don't you make an answer of those, we might get something useful from this.

Comment: Groovy Console version 2.0.1 - running it on a McLeod LoadMaster version 17.2.0

Comment: @HoneyBadger: do feel free to do so...

Answer (score 1):

replace ***and (trailer.inspection_date >= {d '2019-03-26'})*** with ***DateAdd(yyyy,-1,GetDate())***

See if that gives you what you are expecting.

Comment: I get this error - Could not run report - [java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near 'DateAdd'.. Exception received from server: Incorrect syntax near 'DateAdd'. [SqlState: 42000 Error code: 102]]

Groovy Console version 2.0.1 - running it on a McLeod LoadMaster version 17.2.0